# Drupal 7.14 include old removed javascript files

Tags: 7, javascript

I've included at some point some javascript files via :

```
<?php 
drupal_add_js('my_file.js');
?>
```

I removed those files, but now, I've got 404 errors even if there is no call or instructions at all to include them.

I clear my cache, remove cache from database, remove site/all/default/files/js/*...

Don't really know what to do now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you include the file originally?

Comment: In a custom module (hook_block_view).

Comment: Have you tried putting the file BACK and seeing if the 404 errors stop?

Comment: When I put back the file, there is no 404, if I delete the file again, it comes back.

Comment: Look in the code for "my_file.js",probbly you have inlcude it in other places. Don't forget to include .info files in your search.